# Como criar e exibir uma lista de emails com saída json com as informações do formulário

Tags: php, javascript

O objetivo do projeto é gerar uma lista de "emails" vindo do formulário de contato, para mostrar numa lista  do tipo `li` com os seguintes dados:
 - nome
 - assunto
 - horário do envio

Preciso também que o usuário clique em um determinado campo que altere o status de 0 para 1 (significando que foi lido).

O problema está acontecendo no último passo, ao pegar o `id` do usuário, não está atualizando os dados, segue meu código em javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var total_not = document.getElementsByClassName('badge')[0],
                    res = document.getElementById('res');

    window.setInterval(function(){
        xhr.get('../includes/request.php?acao=verificar', function(total){
                total_not.innerHTML = total;
            });
        }, 1000);

        window.setInterval(function(){
            xhr.get('../includes/request.php?acao=getnots', function(nots){
                res.innerHTML = nots;
            });
        }, 1000);

        res.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        var elemento = e.target;

        if(elemento.classList.contains('vis')){
            xhr.get('../includes/request.php?acao=vis&idnot='+elemento.value, function(res){
                    alert(res);
                });
            }else{
                alert('nao entro no if');
            }
    });
});
```

Nele estou adicionando um evento para a `div res`, esta `div` é gerada pelo javascript. Todas essas requisições eu trato na página em PHP `request.php` conforme é apresentado logo abaixo:

```
<?php 
    include_once('conexao.php');

    $POST = $_GET['acao'];

    switch ($POST) {
        case 'contato':

        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $data = date('Y-m-d');
$row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_CONTATOS where TXT_ENDIP_CONTT = '$ip'  and DAT_INCLU_CONTT like '%".$data."%' ");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($row);


        if($count != 0){

            header("Location: ../../paginas/contato.php"); exit; 

        }else{

            $TXT_NOMEX_CONTT = $_GET['TXT_NOMEX_CONTT'];
            $TXT_EMAIL_CONTT = $_GET['TXT_EMAIL_CONTT'];
            $TXT_ASSUN_CONTT = $_GET['TXT_ASSUN_CONTT'];
            $MEM_MENSG_CONTT = $_GET['MEM_MENSG_CONTT'];


        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_CONTATOS (TXT_NOMEX_CONTT, TXT_EMAIL_CONTT, TXT_ASSUN_CONTT, MEM_MENSG_CONTT, DAT_INCLU_CONTT, TXT_ENDIP_CONTT, COD_STATU_ATUAL) VALUES";
    $query .=  "('$TXT_NOMEX_CONTT','$TXT_EMAIL_CONTT','$TXT_ASSUN_CONTT', '$MEM_MENSG_CONTT', now(), '$ip', '0')";

        $inserir = mysql_query($query)
           or die(error());

        mysql_close($conn);

            header("Location: ../../paginas/contato.php"); exit; // Redireciona o visitante
        }

            break;

        case 'verificar':

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_CONTATOS WHERE COD_STATU_ATUAL = '0'");

            $total = mysql_num_rows($query);

            echo $total;

            break;
        case 'getnots':
           $query = mysql_query("SELECT COD_IDENT_CONTT, TXT_NOMEX_CONTT, TXT_ASSUN_CONTT, DAT_INCLU_CONTT FROM tbl_CONTATOS ORDER BY COD_IDENT_CONTT DESC
            ");

            $li = '';

            while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $li .= '<li>';
                $li .= '    <a href="#">';
                $li .= '       <div>';
                $li .= '        <input class="vis" value="'.@$linha[COD_IDENT_CONTT].'" type="hidden"/>';
                $li .= '           <strong>'.@$linha[TXT_NOMEX_CONTT].'</strong>';
                $li .= '           <span class="pull-right text-muted">';
                $li .= '               <em>'.date('d/m/Y H:i', strtotime(@$linha[DAT_INCLU_CONTT])).'</em>';
                $li .= '           </span>';
                $li .= '       </div>';
                $li .= '       <div>'.@$linha[TXT_ASSUN_CONTT].'</div>';
                $li .= '   </a>';
                $li .= '</li>';
                $li .= '<li class="divider"></li>';
            }

            echo $li;
        break;

                case 'vis':
            $idnot = $_GET['idnot'];

         echo $idnot;           

            break;


        default:
            echo 'Erro';
            break;
    }
```

Nesta página eu faço um `switch`, no qual faço a requisição para cada entrada por método `GET`, o erro que está ocorrendo é no `case vis:`. Como podem ver, aparentemente, está faltando parte do código, entretanto, estou solicitando que o código da mensagem seja exibido em um `alert`.

Como solucionar isto?

Comment: no seu JS ali está faltando fechar o código - res.addEventListener('click', function(e){ - não sei se é apenas no código postado ou no q está sendo executado tb. Qual o erro que você está tendo? Se possível add aí uma imagem com o erro

Comment: leitura recomendada [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/13561)

Comment: Você pretende enviar uma lista via json para ser exibida é isso?

Comment: Está faltando isso para fechar seu código: `});` conforme @gildonei apresentou.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seu problema esteja ao adicionar o evento em um elemento que ainda não existe no dom.
Para resolver utilizando js puro, você poderia colocar o evento no documento e detectar qual foi o target, ficando assim:

```js
//[...]

document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.id== 'res'){
      var elemento = e.target;

        if(elemento.classList.contains('vis')){
            xhr.get('../includes/request.php?acao=vis&idnot='+elemento.value, function(res){
                alert(res);
            });
        }else{
            alert('nao entro no if');
        }
    }
})
```

Um outro problema que vejo é que você está pegando o valor da `div res` com `elemento.value`, tente usar `data-value` ao invés disto, atributos customizados devem ser prefixados por `data-`. [motivo aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190859/atributos-personalizados-html)