# Atributos personalizados HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema voltado para gestão de concursos públicos e preciso que o mesmo seja compatível com o maior número de dispositivos possíveis.

Em algumas situações foi necessário o uso de atributos personalizados, exemplo:

```
<span qtd='20'>Alguma coisa...</span>
```

Neste caso, eu pego o valor do qtd através do `Jquery.attr()` e utilizo como necessário, funciona bem nos navegadores mais modernos, mas a questão é:
 **É uma boa prática? Quais problemas posso ter em navegadores mais antigos?**

Comment: Relacionado: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Comment: Na verdade, isso pode gerar problemas em navegadores mais novos, que ainda não existem. Isto é, se no futuro passar a existir um novo atributo HTML com o mesmo nome que você usou, vai dar problema. Por isso criaram o prefixo `data-` no HTML5.

Comment: Bem observado @bfavaretto, exatamente

Comment: Obrigado @bfavaretto, sempre vi esse prefixo mas nem fazia ideia de que era esse o motivo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Não é boa prática.

Para combater isso HTML5 trouxe-nos um meio de alcançares o que queres (atributos costumizados) chamam-se [`data-*`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes), onde podes fazer `data-blahblah` e poupares-te a problemas que possam surgir, nesse caso poderias fazer :

```
<span data-qtd='20'>Alguma coisa...</span>
```

E para ir buscar o atributo com jQuery é só:

```
$('span').data('qtd'); // 20
```

No entanto, existem algumas coisas [a ter em mente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), como isto:

Se fizeres `data-minha-qtd` o DOM converte-te isto para:

> minhaQtd

E poderias aceder assim:

```
$('span').data('minhaQtd');
```

[Um apontamento de alguém que sabe mais do que eu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992115/custom-attributes-yea-or-nay/992307#992307)

Que aponta para [isto](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)

Quanto a compatibilidades de atributos `data` e os navegadores mais antigos, [suponho que não há problema, nem no IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6/2413263#2413263), testes que não foram realizados por mim mas acredito nesse colega do SO EN.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Miguel, esclareceu bastante pra mim. Abraço

Comment: De nada @edsonalves