# Como criar um atributo para uma tag HTML? Algo semelhante ao já existente "required"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho uma pagina com vários `<input>` e alguns deles são obrigatórios, esses `<input>` não estão em uma tag `<form>`, logo, creio que o `required` não consegue trabalhar nessa situação. Tenho feito a verificação na mão mesmo:

```
if(codBarras == null || codBarras == '')
    toastr.error('O Código de Barras é obrigatório!');
else if(dataVencimento == null || dataVencimento == '')
    toastr.error('A Data de Vencimento é obrigatório!');
else
    console.log('Faça algo!');
```

Porém, eu gostaria de saber se é possível criar uma espécie de atributo para eu colocar nos `<input>` para fazer essa verificação, ficando da seguinte maneira:

**Até o momento:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="iptCodBarras">
```

**Após a criação do atributo:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="iptCodBarras" needed="true">
```

Minha intenção seria colocar o "atributo" `needed="true"` nos `<input>` que eu gostaria que fossem obrigatórios.

**Resposta:**

Segui a resposta do Marcel Felipe e consegui exatamente o que eu precisava, aproveitei o inicio `each` que ele menciona na resposta e criei o seguinte bloco:

```
var emBranco = 0;
$("[needed=true]").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == null)
    {
        emBranco++;
        toastr.error('Existem campos obrigatórios em branco!');
        $(this).css({'border': '1px solid salmon'});
        $(this).on('focus', function(){
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
        });
    }
});
if(emBranco == 0)
    console.log('Todos os campos obrigatorios estão preenchidos!');
```

O bloco anterior verifica todos os `<inputs>` que estão com o atributo `needed="true"` se estão preenchidos, caso algum não esteja, irá incrementar a variável `emBranco` e mostrar o `toastr` de erro, caso todos estão preenchidos, a variavel terá continuará com o valor 0 e executará a ação desejada. Os `<inputs>` que estiverem em branco, irão ficar com a borda avermelhada (semelhante ao `required`) e quando o usuário clicar nesses `<inputs>` em branco, removerá a borda avermelhada.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Atributos personalizados HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190859/atributos-personalizados-html)

Comment: `data-needed` é o indicado pela documentação oficial, assim como está na resposta linkada pelo @NoobSaibot

Comment: @NoobSaibot A ideia do `data-*` é excelente e muito bem-vinda, mas a resposta do Marcel resolveu perfeitamente minha pergunta e ainda registrou aqui no StackOverflow uma técnica que eu creio que não são todos que conhecem. Talvez minha pergunta possa ser duplicata, mas obtive sucesso e ainda um conhecimento novo, acho valida a permanência da pergunta para aprendizado de outras pessoas que passarem por aqui.

Comment: @J.Thatcher Duplicata não significa que tenha de ser removida. A pergunta mesmo como duplicata deve permanecer pois muitas vezes é outro ponto de entrada para chegar ao mesmo problema. Outra forma de chegar ao mesmo problema por pesquisa no Google. O que o duplicata indica é que as respostas não se devem repetir pois são as mesmas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode alterar sua declaração DOCTYPE, ficaria assim:

```
<!ATTLIST element-name attribute-name attribute-type attribute-value>

DTD example:
<!ATTLIST input obrigatorio CDATA "true">

XML example:
<input type="text" obrigatorio="true" />
```

Ao buscar o atributo pela tag o javascript o reconhece:

```html
<!ATTLIST element-name attribute-name attribute-type attribute-value>

DTD example:
<!ATTLIST input obrigatorio CDATA "true">

XML example:
<input type="text" obrigatorio="true" />

<script type="text/javascript">
 alert(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].getAttribute('obrigatorio'));
</script>
```

Usando Jquery você pode buscar todos os elementos que possuem o atributo e fazer uma validação dinâmica:

```
$("[obrigatorio=true]").each(function(data){
    if(!data) alert("Inválido");
});
```

Você pode ler mais sobre isso no seguinte link: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_attributes.asp

Comment: Toda vez que quiser criar um novo atributo terá que adicionar `<!ATTLIST input nome_atributo CDATA "true">` no código? Pergunto porque é a primeira vez que vejo isso.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Mas recomendo você a verificar bem os atributos da sua tag antes de criar novos, pode ser que o que você precisa já exista.

Comment: Interessante essa ideia. Estou pensando em verificar o `value` dos `<input>` que estiverem com a tag `obrigatorio=true`, caso seja `null` ou vazio, aciono a mensagem de campo obrigatório. Acha que é possivel?

Comment: Entendi, não fui eu que criei a pergunta. Bom, mais não seria mais fácil utilizar `data-*`? Como na pergunta marcada como duplicata? [**Atributos personalizados HTML**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190859/atributos-personalizados-html)

Comment: Agora que eu acabei de ver o link que você marcou no comentário, me parece melhor sim, essa é uma ideia que eu não conhecia.

Comment: @J.Thatcher é sim, veja o código JQuery que eu coloquei no final da resposta

Comment: Consegui atingir meu objetivo com sua resposta e ainda aprendi algo novo, algo que eu nunca tinha ouvido falar. Vlw!

Answer (score 0):

Use uma `classe` para os inputs obrigatórios.

Para cada input sem value recupere o valor do atributo `data-id` e concatene-os a fim de apresentar em uma div.

**1 - exemplo sem código de barras e sem data de vencimento**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var erros = "";
 $('.obrigatorio').each(function (i, el) {
    var data = $(el).val();
           if(data == null || data == ''){
              erros += ($(this).attr("data-id") + "<br>");
              $(this).css({'border': '1px solid salmon'});
           }
           var len = data.length;
           if (len<1) {
               $( ".error" ).html(erros);
               event.preventDefault();
               return;
           }
       });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="error"></div>

1 <input type="text" name="codBarras" value="" data-id="O Codigo de Barras é obrigatorio" class="obrigatorio">
  <br/>
2 <input type="text" name="dataVencimento" value="" data-id="A Data Vencimento é obrigatória" class="obrigatorio">
  <br/>
3 <input type="text" name="c" value="" data-id="Não obrigatorio" class="nao" placeholder="Não obrigatório">
```

**2 - exemplo sem data de vencimento nulo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var erros = "";
 $('.obrigatorio').each(function (i, el) {
    var data = $(el).val();
           if(data == null || data == ''){
              erros += ($(this).attr("data-id") + "<br>");
              $(this).css({'border': '1px solid salmon'});
           }
           var len = data.length;
           if (len<1) {
               $( ".error" ).html(erros);
               event.preventDefault();
               return;
           }
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="error"></div>

1 <input type="text" name="codBarras" value="2134567455676" data-id="O Codigo de Barras é obrigatorio" class="obrigatorio">
  <br/>
2 <input type="text" name="dataVencimento" value="" data-id="A Data Vencimento é obrigatória" class="obrigatorio">
  <br/>
3 <input type="text" name="c" value="" data-id="Não obrigatorio" class="nao" placeholder="Não obrigatório">
```