# Pegar todas as div dentro de um tbody sem jquery

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte estrutura em meu HTML:

```
    <!-- O número de tbody's sera gerado dinamicamente, de acordo com o número de estados -->
<tbody name="tbodyEstados">
    <tr style="background:#F5F5F5;">
        <td>
            Nome do estado
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- o número de div's será gerado dinamicamente -->
            <div name="divOficina">
                <label>
                    Nome de uma oficina
                    <input type="hidden" value="id_do_objeto">
                </label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Através do javascript, estou usando a função document.getElementsByName('tbodyEstados') para obter um array com todos os tbody's de estados, mas depois preciso iterar cada um dos itens dessa lista e pegar de dentro deles, separadamente para cada estado,  os elementos div que estão com o nome: "divOficina". Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: O elemento `tbody` não deve se repetir várias vezes na mesma table. Revise sua lógica. Você poderia pegar diretamente as divs `divOficina` com `document.getElementsByName('divOficina')`

Comment: O problema de usar diretamente document.getElementsByName('divOficina') é que não terei como saber quais destas div's estão dentro de qual estado especificamente.

Comment: Adicione um atributo de estado ao escrever a div. Ex.: `<div name=divOficina estado=DF>...</div>`. Ao fazer um loop na divs, vc verifica o attributo assim: `minhaDivOficina.getAttribute('estado')`.

Comment: É recomendado que atributos customizados sejam prefixados por `data-` para evitar incompatibilidades https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190859/atributos-personalizados-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes dividir a pesquisa em dois passos, primeiro com `document.getElementsByName('tbodyEstados');` e depois com `tBody.getElementsByName('divOficina');` dentro de um loop executas a lógica que precisas. Algo assim:

```
const tbodyEstados = document.getElementsByName('tbodyEstados');
tbodyEstados.forEach(parent => {
    const divOficina = parent.getElementsByName('divOficina');
    // aqui podes usar `divOficina ` e `parent` que são respectivamente o 
    // elemento interior e exterior que procuras...
});
```